# NOT NULL constraint failed: qaforum_question.survey_id

Tags: django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question) + "-" + str(self.id)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: qaforum_question.survey_id
```

I went through similar questions on the site and I have set the "null" parameter to "True". 
Please, help.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you run `manage.py make migrations` and `manage.py migrate` yet?

Comment: Yes, I did "makemigrations" command works but "migrate" command gives the error. But I deleted all migrations and I wrote the whole models code again and migrated them one by one and it worked. But I would still like to know the reason.

Comment: Well the reason you were getting the `NOT NULL constraint` error is that if you don't apply your migrations, your database isn't actually updated. So your code would have allowed that field to be null, but the database parameters wouldn't.

Comment: The reason for why your migrate call was failing on the other hand, I can't help you with unless you have more information.